# R: Create conditional variable based on factor level of one variable and assign to all rows of same group

Tags: r, conditional-statements, r-factor

Here is an example of my data. Column "first_tx" is my desired output:

```
ID   first_date   dates        txtype     first_tx
11   2015-12-23   2015-12-23   A          A
11   2015-12-23   2016-12-23   A          A
11   2015-12-23   2017-12-23   B          A
22   2015-11-01   2015-11-01   B          B
22   2015-11-01   2016-11-01   C          B
22   2015-11-01   2016-12-01   C          B
```

I am trying to create "first_tx" by group, based on the factor level of "txtype" when "first_date" is equal to "dates"

I tried

```
data$first_tx[which(data$first_date==data$dates)] <- as.character(data$txtype)[which(data$first_date==data$dates)]
```

This gave me the following output:

```
ID   first_date   dates        txtype     first_tx
11   2015-12-23   2015-12-23   A          A
11   2015-12-23   2016-12-23   A          NA
11   2015-12-23   2017-12-23   B          NA
22   2015-11-01   2015-11-01   B          B
22   2015-11-01   2016-11-01   C          NA
22   2015-11-01   2016-12-01   C          NA
```

However, instead of NAs, I would like all rows for each ID to have the same corresponding "txtype" level.

Comment: Can not you do: `data$first_tx[which(data$first_date!=data$dates)] <-data$ID[which(data$first_date!=data$dates)]`

Answer (score 1):

By using `dplyr` and `tidyr` I can create your expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(first_tx = ifelse(first_date == dates, txtype, NA)) %>% 
  fill(first_tx)

  ID first_date      dates txtype first_tx
1 11 2015-12-23 2015-12-23      A        A
2 11 2015-12-23 2016-12-23      A        A
3 11 2015-12-23 2017-12-23      B        A
4 22 2015-11-01 2015-11-01      B        B
5 22 2015-11-01 2016-11-01      C        B
6 22 2015-11-01 2016-12-01      C        B
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 22L, 22L, 22L), 
               first_date = c("2015-12-23", "2015-12-23", "2015-12-23", "2015-11-01", "2015-11-01", "2015-11-01"), 
               dates = c("2015-12-23", "2016-12-23", "2017-12-23", "2015-11-01", "2016-11-01", "2016-12-01"), 
               txtype = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")),
          .Names = c("ID", "first_date", "dates", "txtype"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was hopeful but this didn't work... for some reason, the result was all 3's for first_tx. I also have used "mutate" before and have always come across the same problem, where the new variable is not actually added onto the original data frame, and only shows the first 20 rows like a tibble.

Comment: do you assign the mutate to the dataframe? like `df <- df  %>% mutate...` etc ?

Answer (score 0):

are you tring something like this??

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(
  ID = c('11', '11', '11', '22', '22', '22'),
  first_date = c('2015-12-23', '2015-12-23', '2015-12-23', '2015-11-01', '2015-11-01', '2015-11-01'),
  dates = c('2015-12-23', '2016-12-23', '2017-12-23', '2015-11-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01'),
  txtype = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')
)


data[first_date == dates,
     ':='(first_tx = txtype),
     by = .(txtype)]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the first_tx was my desired output column, not part of my original data set.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it and this worked:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(first_tx = {if (first_date == dates) txtype[min(which(first_date == dates))] else NA})
```

Thank you @phiver for your help!